# Why does browser closes automatically when latest version of WebDriverManager (5 onward) is used, is its new feature?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

I recently created a new Selenium Maven project using the latest version(5.2.1) of WebDriverManager but I found that without using driver.quit() or driver.close() method, the browser closed automatically after test execution, is it a new feature of WebDriverManager (5 onward)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [WebDriverManager doc](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/), when you use the method `create()` for building `WebDriver` objects, WebDriverManager includes a shutdown hook that watches these objects correctly released before shutting down the JVM. If you want to avoid this behavior, you can use the method `avoidShutdownHook()`, for instance as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().avoidShutdownHook().create();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so considering this shutdown hook I will not need a tearDown() method (@AfterMethod in TestNg) to quit the driver if I haven't avoided it, right?

Comment: When using WebDriverManager's `create()` method, yes, you can relay in WebDriverManager to close browsers gracefully.